# Fetch video data from YouTube on the fly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, youtube, youtube-api

In my form, a user pastes (or types) the URL of the video from YouTube. When this happens I need to be able to fetch the relevant data from YouTube and pre-populate certain fields, e.g. title, description and width/height.

The problem I'm having is the only examples I can find of this are where you already have the id of the video you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src =
 "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<VideoID>?v=2&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=FeedCallback"
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function FeedCallback( data )
  {
   //get title from YouTube Data API via JSON
   document.getElementById('Title').innerHTML = data.entry[ "title" ].$t;
  }
</script>
```

But this will only work if I already know `<VideoID>` when the View is loaded, which I don't? Is there any way to resolve the ID in the view and then use that to return the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing the URL entered to get the `(id)`, I used the following function:

```
function fetch_data(id) {
    var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $('input#DataProvider_Title').val(data.entry.title.$t);
        $('textarea#DataProvider_Description').val(data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t);
    });
}
```